# Вывести номера недель (год) в каждом периоде (месяц)

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

Есть цикл который выводит номера недель каждого месяца нужное количество раз.
И вот если к примеру, мы выберем начало недели - понедельник freq='W-MON', а месяц начинается не в понедельник. то цикл выводит номера недель с ПЕРВОГО ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИКА месяца, а нужно с номера недели куда попадает 01 число.
К примеру декабрь 2021г. начинается в среду - 48 неделя, НО цикл первой печатает 49 неделю, с 06.12.2021. - Это логично.
Но мне нужно что бы он показывал номер недели относящийся к промежуточным неделям. т.е что бы в декабре 2021 вывод начался с 48 неделе.

```
    # количество повторений
    n_repeat = 1
    # полученный период
    month_year = '11.2021'
    month_year = '01.' + str(month_year)  
    month_year = datetime.strptime(month_year, '%d.%m.%Y')  
    
    # Получаем первый и последний день месяца отчета
    first_day = pd.to_datetime(month_year).replace(day=1)
    last_day = (pd.to_datetime(first_day) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).date()
    
    for dt in pd.date_range(start=first_day, end = last_day, freq='W-MON').repeat(n_repeat).sort_values():
        datss = dt.date()
        print(datss.strftime('%W'))
        print(datss)#.strftime('%W')
```

Comment: первые дни года часто находятся в неделе предыдущего. и тогда первая неделя начинается позже http://tipografiya-ms.ru/poleznoe/nedeli_schet.htm

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, информативно, осталось это объяснить бухгалтерии))))

Comment: они обязаны это знать

Comment: @splash58
Увидел, что возникла другая проблема: 
к примеру, мы выберем начало недели - понедельник freq='W-MON', а месяц начинается не в понедельник. то цикл выводит номера недель с ПЕРВОГО ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИКА месяца, а нужно с номера недели куда попадает 01 число. К примеру декабрь 2021г. начинается в среду - 48 неделя, НО цикл первой печатает 49 неделю, с 06.12.2021. - Это логично. Но мне нужно что бы он показывал номер недели относящийся к промежуточным неделям. т.е что бы в декабре 2021 вывод начался с 48 неделе.

Comment: а зачем freq='W-MON - вам же все дни месяца надо 'D' ?

Comment: @splash58
О, а че так можно было))
Блин, но тогда он делает 31 вывод номеров недель, а мне нужны выводы по количеству недель. Нужно докрутить цикл, да!?

Comment: видимо, да  :). можно двухуровневый индекс сделать, если нужно именно в pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [62]: n_repeat = 2

In [63]: for d in pd.date_range(first_day, first_day + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(), freq="7D").repeat(n_repeat):
    ...:     print(f"date: {d:%Y-%m-%d}, week: {d.isocalendar()[1]}")
    ...:
date: 2021-11-01, week: 44
date: 2021-11-01, week: 44
date: 2021-11-08, week: 45
date: 2021-11-08, week: 45
date: 2021-11-15, week: 46
date: 2021-11-15, week: 46
date: 2021-11-22, week: 47
date: 2021-11-22, week: 47
date: 2021-11-29, week: 48
date: 2021-11-29, week: 48
```

---

Декабрь 2021:

```
In [64]: first_day = pd.to_datetime("2021-12-01")

In [65]: for d in pd.date_range(first_day, first_day + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(), freq="7D").repeat(n_repeat):
    ...:     print(f"date: {d:%Y-%m-%d}, week: {d.isocalendar()[1]}")
    ...:
date: 2021-12-01, week: 48
date: 2021-12-01, week: 48
date: 2021-12-08, week: 49
date: 2021-12-08, week: 49
date: 2021-12-15, week: 50
date: 2021-12-15, week: 50
date: 2021-12-22, week: 51
date: 2021-12-22, week: 51
date: 2021-12-29, week: 52
date: 2021-12-29, week: 52
```

Comment: отлично, это то что нужно!